# Approximating ordered list with minimum number of comparisons

Tags: paired-comparisons

I have a [small app for helping with ranking of items](https://github.com/WilkaH/orange-apple). It uses lots of pairwise comparisons done by a human. I'd like to minimize the number of comparisons the human needs to do, while still getting close to the ideal ranking for each item (where "ideal" is what the human would produce if they considered every pair of items).

I've found a [StackOverflow question asking the same kind of thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914129/which-sorting-algorithms-give-near-approximate-sort-sooner) but I'm wondering if there's something I should be using from the stats world, rather than just considering sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do pretty well simply by adding one for every won pairing and subtracting one for every loss. Over time low priority things will be heavily negative. High priority things highly positive. Keep asking people to compare pairs they haven't seen before that rank close together.